# how to get Apache to reload php.ini in WIndows XP?

Tags: xdebug, php

I'm trying to install XDebug by registering it in php.ini but it isn't working. I'm thinking maybe my apache server is not reloading my changes properly.

-from your friendly PHP noob

Answer (score 1):

Try `httpd -k restart`

See [Using Apache With Microsoft Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/platform/windows.html) for more help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this reference:

[XDEBUG Installation](http://programmingbulls.com/debugging-drupal-php--xdebug-eclipse)